# Como fazer um "rbind" em tabelas de uma base SQL a partir do R?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

Eu gostaria de "fundir" duas tabelas de um "database" SQLite a partir do R -- e salvar isso numa nova tabela dentro do mesmo database. Abaixo, envio um código mínimo reprodutível:

```
    install.packages("sqldf",dependencies=T)
    install.packages("RSQLite",dependencies=T)
    library(sqldf)

    A <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2=55:59)
    B <- data.frame(var1 = 11:15, var2=155:159)

    drv <- dbDriver("SQLite") 
    con <- dbConnect(drv, "basequalquer.db") 
    dbWriteTable(con, "TabelaA", A) 
    dbWriteTable(con, "TabelaB", B)
```

O resultado que desejo é esse aqui:

```
    dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM TabelaA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TabelaB' )

       row_names var1 var2
    1          1    1   55
    2          2    2   56
    3          3    3   57
    4          4    4   58
    5          5    5   59
    6          1   11  155
    7          2   12  156
    8          3   13  157
    9          4   14  158
    10         5   15  159
```

Consigo fazer uma query para obtê-lo, mas não sei como salvar isso diretamente no database (ou seja, sem que eu tenha que guarda-lo num data.frame e depois fazer dbWriteTable)

Comment: Acho que quando você instala o sqldf o RSQLite vem de brinde como dependência.

O pulo do gato do sqldf é que você não precisa usar o dbWriteTable, quando existe um data.frame X e você usa sqldf("SELECT * FROM X") o df X é automaticamente copiado para o SQLite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não deve ser a única forma de fazer, mas tente colocando o comando `CREATE TABLE` na própria query:

```
dbGetQuery(con, 'CREATE TABLE TabelaC AS
                 SELECT * FROM TabelaA 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT * FROM TabelaB' )
```

Testando se a tabela foi criada:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from Tabelac")
   row_names var1 var2
1          1    1   55
2          2    2   56
3          3    3   57
4          4    4   58
5          5    5   59
6          1   11  155
7          2   12  156
8          3   13  157
9          4   14  158
10         5   15  159
```

Comment: Simples assim... valeu, Carlos

Answer (score 7):

Deixa eu adicionar meus 2 centavos: a solução do Carlos está correta, MAS nessa solução você vai copiar cada entrada das duas tabelas em uma nova tabela e elas não estarão mais relacionadas, isto é, qualquer mudança nas tabelas originais não será refletida nessa nova tabela criada no merge.

Um recurso que o SQLite3 e outros sistemas de gerenciamento de banco de dados tem,  é a VIEW (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) que permite que você crie o mesmo merge de antes, só que a tabela é sensível às mudanças na tabela original. Se você inserir ou retirar registros da TabelaA ou TabelaB, ao consultar a VIEW as mudanças estarão presentes lá também.

```
library(sqldf)

   A <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2=55:59)
   B <- data.frame(var1 = 11:15, var2=155:159)

   drv <- dbDriver("SQLite") 
   con <- dbConnect(drv, "basequalquer.db") 
   dbWriteTable(con, "TabelaA", A) 
   dbWriteTable(con, "TabelaB", B) 

   ## Criando a VIEW
   dbGetQuery(con, 'CREATE VIEW
                    merge
                 AS
                    SELECT * FROM TabelaA 
                        UNION ALL 
                    SELECT * FROM TabelaB')

   ## Fazendo uma consulta na VIEW
   dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM merge')

 row_names var1 var2
1          1    1   55
2          2    2   56
3          3    3   57
4          4    4   58
5          5    5   59
6          1   11  155
7          2   12  156
8          3   13  157
9          4   14  158
10         5   15  159

   ## Removendo uma linha da TabelaA
   dbGetQuery(con, 'DELETE FROM TabelaA WHERE row_names = 3')

   ## Consultando a VIEW novamente
   ## veja que o registro sumiu da VIEW também!
   dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM merge')

 row_names var1 var2
1         1    1   55
2         2    2   56
3         4    4   58
4         5    5   59
5         1   11  155
6         2   12  156
7         3   13  157
8         4   14  158
9         5   15  159
```

Comment: Muito interessante, @Flavio!

Mas e se eu quiser uma terceira forma: como fundir TabelaA e TabelaB, fazendo com que elas agora deixem de existir (para ocupar menos memória).

Ou seja, como empilhar as duas, sem criar cópia? Eu sei que poderia deletar as tabelas originais depois. Mas se eu só as deletasse depois, por alguns momentos as originais e a cópia existirão simultaneamente. Se a base de dados for realmente muito grande, imagino situações em que isso pode não ser viável.

Comment: @RogerioJB, seria o caso de usar o comando do Carlos Cinelli sem o UNION ALL, dropar a tabela, e rodar um INSERT INTO TabelaC SELECT FROM TabelaB.

Mas se você estiver mexendo com bases de dados tão grandes que não dá pra fazer o UNION ALL, já passou da hora de trocar R+SQLite por Python+NoSQL :)

Comment: Ou ainda, usar o pacote ff: http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2007/program/presentations/adler.pdf

Comment: Olá @Lucass, obrigado pela dica. O ff eu conheço. Mas estou mesmo com dúvidas no SQLite+R... Mas eu não entendi a sua   dica. Como faço pra usar o CREATE TABLE sem o UNION ALL para esse caso?

Comment: Fazer em etapas. Primeiro o CREATE TABLE inserindo os dados da tabela A, sem UNION ALL. Após isso, apaga-se a tabela A. Faz-se então o INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM Tabela B, e depois apaga-se a tabela B. É a única forma de minimizar a replicação sem usar Views (que seria minha abordagem preferida).